# Why does Chrome require Secure for SameSite=None cookies?

Tags: cookies, same-site-cookies

As I understand it, the `SameSite` attribute for cookies helps me advise standard browsers what they can do with them.

So if I'm a server running on http://acme.com/my-app and I've set a cookie like:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1234567890abcdef; SameSite=Strict
```

If the user is on https://www.facebook.com, the browser will stop it from sending me requests with the cookie `JSESSIONID` (for fear of them executing malicious code).

If I want my cookie to be used for cross-site requests I need to set `SameSite` to `None` [(which used to be default but is now `Lax`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite).

However, browsers also require that cookies with this attribute also have the attribute `Secure` (example from the docs):

```
Set-Cookie: flavor=choco; SameSite=None; Secure
```

What I don't understand is *why*. I understand why SSL connections are more secure and why we would prefer both SSL and the attributes `SameSite=Strict` and `Secure` for our cookies where possible.

But why enforce `Secure` only for cross-site cookies and not for all cookies? It obviously doesn't prevent any website using the cookie to execute requests (that's what `SameSite` is for). So https://evil-evil.com can just as easily send me the user's `SameSite=None` cookies as https://facebook.com. Sure, we prevent [snooping and third-party monitoring (man-in-the-middle)](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032), but we also have that problem for `SameSite=Strict` cookies. I.e. the bad people can still steal the cookies I send over the insecure http://acme.com/my-app/perform-sensitive-action.

So why enforce `Secure` for some types of cookies except that Google said so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a privacy measure intended to mitigate pervasive monitoring of network traffic by ISPs, governments, and other network actors.

The motivation is explained in detail in [section 3.2 of the IETF draft [draft-west-cookie-incrementalism-01]](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-incrementalism-01#section-3.2):

> Requiring "Secure" for "SameSite=None"
>
> Cookies sent over plaintext HTTP are visible to anyone on the network. As section 8.3 of [[RFC6265bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-incrementalism-01#ref-RFC6265bis)] points out, this visibility exposes substantial amounts of data to network attackers.  We know, for example, that long-lived and stable cookies have enabled pervasive monitoring [[RFC7258](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7258)] in the past (see Google's PREF cookie [[pref-cookie](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-incrementalism-01#ref-pref-cookie)]), and we know that a secure transport layer provides significant confidentiality protections against this kind of attack.
>
> We can, to a reasonable extent, mitigate this threat by ensuring that cookies intended for cross-site delivery (and therefore likely to be more prevalent on the wire than cookies scoped down to same-site requests) require secure transport.

As for why this isn't enforced for all cookies, that's likely a compromise intended to balance the privacy improvements of secure cookies against the harm of breaking existing plaintext HTTP sites that rely on first-party cookies. As HTTPS adoption on the web becomes more widespread, it's possible browsers may eventually move to restrict cookies entirely to secure contexts.

Comment: Thank you, that helps somewhat. What I still don't quite understand is "therefore likely to be more prevalent on the wire." Why is that the case for cross-site cookies more than same-site?

Comment: @Druckles It means cross-site cookies get sent/received more frequently than first-party cookies, so there's more opportunity for them to be intercepted by attackers. Cross-site cookies are often used for things like ad targeting and social media share buttons, so unlike first party cookies they get sent a lot even when you aren't using the site they're set for.